# Google Cloud Pub/Sup API: Almost 100% Errors on StreamingPull

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to use GCP Pub/Sub StreamingPull using the NodeJs client and I understand that the pub sub is designed for 100% error rate as mentioned in [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull_has_a_100_error_rate_this_is_to_be_expected).

So do I have to restart the listener if I face errors in the errorHandler and also please tell what error code should I be looking for to see if the streaming connection is closed. Here is the ref [Error Codes](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/error-codes)

```
const errorHandler=(error)=>{
    if(errorCodeCheckCondition){
        subscription.on('message', messageHandler);
        subscription.removeListener('message', messageHandler);
    }

}
subscription.on('error', errorHandler);
```

I'm using GCP Pub/Sub StreamingPull for first time, so please guide.

Comment: Hi @Kaneki21 If my answer addressed your question, consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well

Comment: Thanks Sayan for the answer... I have upvoted it already. Can you please tell if the errorHandler which I wrote is correct or not, I'm also doing some R&D on exponential backoff

Comment: You should re-establish the connection instead of just adding another listener for the previous connection. `subscription.on('message', messageHandler);` this won't work if your connection is already closed.You can check the connection status by calling `subscription.isOpen`. Let me know if this help you.

Comment: So you mean reinitating the subscription is the correct solution ?
subscription = pubSubClient.subscription(subscriptionName);
I'm using this for first time so please bear with me

Comment: Not an issue :) . As I said you need to check whether even after any error connection is still available or not . As From @Kamal answered you can also use the retying policy.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to re-establish the streaming pull connection after you get any error. 
According to the [**rpc StreamingPull**](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#subscriber)

> The server will close the stream and return the status on any error. The server may close the stream with status `UNAVAILABLE` to reassign server-side resources, in which case, the client should re-establish the stream. Flow control can be achieved by configuring the underlying RPC channel.

Since You know about **StreamingPull has a 100% error rate**, I believe you must have also gone through the [Diagnosing StreamingPull errors](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#diagnosing_streamingpull_errors).

Answer (score 1):

The Pub/Sub client library will re-establish the underlying streaming pull connection when it disconnects for a retriable reason, e.g., an `UNAVAILABLE` error. You can see in the [`StreamingPull` config](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/9bd2a28eaf8b4416f38f93552dfbecfa454c47e0/src/v1/subscriber_client_config.json#L78-L82) in the library the set of errors that are retried internally.

The errors you would typically get back at the application level would be ones where some additional intervention is likely necessary, e.g., a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error (where the subscriber does not have permission to receive messages on the subscription) or a `NOT_FOUND` error (where the subscription does not exist. Retrying on these types of errors is likely just to result in the error reoccurring until the underlying issue is resolved.

You could decide that retrying is what you want to do because you want the subscriber to start working again without having to manually restart it once other steps are taken to fix the problem, but you'll want to make sure you have some way to discover these types of issues, perhaps through some kind of [Cloud Monitoring alerting](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts) on streaming pull errors or on a large number of unprocessed messages building up.